# how to check if a number is whole number or contains a decimal

Tags: perl, int

If a number is `2017` and I divide it by `4`, I get `504.25`.

if the number is `2016` an I divide it by `4`, I get `504`.

My question is, is there a way to use perl to check if a number that was divided, if the answer is a whole number and has `NO` decimal at all?

UPDATE: I got it working from the answer I selected below. I was trying to check if this is leap year, because today my code broke, because my code ran from the cron job as set to run on the last day of every month. Typically for feb, that is the 28th, so it ran on the 28th and shut the website done for the end of month maintenance. so what I have it do now is run on both Feb 28th and Feb 29th (For if there is a 29th) and in the code, I have it check if it is leap year now like this:

```
my $_leapNum = 4; # Leap year is always divisible by 4 with no remainder...
my $_NotLeapRemain = $_lTimeYYYY % $_leapNum; # I have $_lTimeYYYY built for the year only - longyear

if($_NotLeapRemain) {
    my $_isLeapYear = 0;
} else {
    my $_isLeapYear = 1;
}
```

Then later I check if it is leap year. If it is, then I check if the day is 28th, if it is, then it just exits. If it is the 29th, then it does what it was intended to do.

I tested it and it works perfectly now.

Thank you for your help.
-Rich

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20do%20I%20determine%20whether%20a%20scalar%20is%20a%20number%2Fwhole%2Finteger%2Ffloat%3F

Comment: Use modulo operator [described here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators)

Comment: You mean like... `$ perl -e 'print 2016 % 4'`?

Comment: no, in a perl Script...

Comment: `print "Not evenly divisible.\n" if $dividend % $divisor;`

Comment: so if I go: $_str1 = 2016; $_str2 = $_str1 / 4; print "Not Even\n" if $_str1 % 4; that works?

Comment: @MattJacob - correct in a perl script. sorry, I did not make that clear. My bad.

Comment: The modulo operator returns the "remainder" of a dividend divided by a divisor. In elementary school we learned that a remainder only exists if the dividend is not evenly divisible by the divisor. You are asking exactly that; is there a way to detect if a dividend is not evenly divisible by a divisor.  Oh, and MattJacob did provide @Richard Jones with a Perl script. The part after the -e, between the ' and ' is a Perl script.

Comment: @jm666 I'm using it in my Perl script.

Comment: Re. your edit: you should really use a date-time library for this. For example, the core module [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) has the methods `is_leap_year` and `month_last_day`. Writing your own date-time logic is error-prone: your current solution [incorrectly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar) says that the year 2100 is a leap year.

Comment: The rule is that a year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4, *unless* it is a century, when it is a leap year only if It is divisible by 400. So 2000 was a leap year, but 1900 was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if the result of dividing a `$dividend` by a `$divisor` is going to be a whole number or a number with a fractional portion, you can test that condition first:

```
if (my $remainder = $dividend % $divisor) {
    print "$dividend cannot be divided evenly by $divisor.",
          " There is a remainder of $remainder.\n";
}
else {
    print "$dividend is evenly divisible by $divisor,",
          " and the result is ", $divident / $divisor, "\n";
}
```

*EDIT: * This answer was posted in response to the original, un-edited question, which asked how to determine if the result of division contains a decimal portion.  Now that the sense of the question changed toward date math, I agree that a DateTime solution is much better.